# Error #1064 al crear un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas intento hacer un kardex y el proceso de lo movimientos lo quiero realizar con un procedimiento almacenado.

Este es el Modelo relacional de la base de datos:

[image: Este es el Modelo relacional de la base de datos]
Donde producto_cod de la tabla kardex es la id_producto de la tabla producto y el campo concepto es de tipo enum('Entrada','Salida') de la tabla kardex.

El procedimiento que necesito hacer es que cada que ingrese en la tabla kardex un producto con su campo cantidad eje:1 y en la opción concepto es igual a 'Entrada' me actualice la tabla producto con la cantidad ingresad. Lo mismo con la opcion salida.

Eje: si en la tabla producto tengo un producto con la cantidad 5 y en la tabla kardex selecciono el producto y le doy la opción de entrada y en la cantidad ingreso 3 entonces la tabla producto de ese producto  la cantidad quedaría en  8, y así mismo en salida ya que en esta se resta.

Actualmente tengo este codigo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZA_STOCK (n_cantidad int,  n_concepto enum, id int)
BEGIN
if n_concepto='Entrada' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad+n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if
if n_concepto='Salida' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad-n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if;
END $$
```

pero me sale el sgte error:

**#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ' id int)
   BEGIN
   if n_concepto='Entrada' then
   UPDATE producto set cantidad=cant' en la linea 1**

Se les agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error mayor, y es que las columnas del tipo `ENUM` no se crean así, sino con sus valores.

Del tipo de dato `ENUM` la  [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) dice lo siguiente:

> Un `ENUM` es un objeto de cadena con un valor seleccionado de **una
>   lista de valores** permitidos **que se enumeran explícitamente en la
>   especificación de columna en el momento de la creación de la tabla**.

Por ejemplo,, la sintaxis de una columna `ENUM`  para crear, insertar, seleccionar, es algo como esto:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);

INSERT INTO shirts (name, size) VALUES ('dress shirt','large'), ('t-shirt','medium'),
  ('polo shirt','small');

SELECT name, size FROM shirts WHERE size = 'medium';
```

Tu declaración de `n_concepto enum` no cumple con esos criterios, por eso el error. También, te falta un punto y coma al final de un if, pero eso es un error menor que se corrige poniendo el punto y coma.

Probé esto en rextester y funciona, **observa la columna del tipo `enum` como es creada**:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/PHWM8100)</kbd>

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZA_STOCK  
(n_cantidad int, n_concepto enum('Entrada', 'Salida'),  id int) 
BEGIN 
if n_concepto='Entrada' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad+n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if;
if n_concepto='Salida' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad-n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if;
END;$$
```

Comment: Hice lo que me comentas pero en n_concepto lo coloque asi: n_concepto('Entrada','Salida') pero igual me sale un error y es el sgt: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'if n_concepto='Salida' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad-n_cantidad WH' en la linea 6.

Comment: @Juanzu te faltó indicar el tipo de dato. O sea: **`n_concepto enum('Entrada','Salida') .. `** Y no olvides poner el punto y coma al primer **`end if`**

Comment: Que pena contigo se me olvido colocarlo en el comentario pero si lo tengo con enum. quedaria asi: n_concepto enum('Entrada','Salida'),

Comment: Correcto, así debe quedar. Como puedes ver en el [demo de rextester](http://rextester.com/PHWM8100) la procedure se crea sin problemas. **¿Pusiste el punto y coma al final del primer `end if`?**  Si haciendo todo eso  te da error, puede que tengas algún problema con el `DELIMITER`.

Comment: Pero raro, analizo letra por letra el código y lo veo bien. Será que hay algún inconveniente por lo que el campo concepto de la tabla kardex hay que mostrarla en el procedimiento? Bueno voy a seguir pensando haber si puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: @Juanzu No creo, en ese caso te daría error al llamar la procedure, no al crearla. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora y el error que está dando?

Comment: Me disculpo contigo, ya me funciono. Volví a revisar letra por letra y me faltaba un ";" pero ahora me sale es un error pero cuando llamo el procedimiento desde php con PDO, pero pues en esa publicare otra pregunta, Se te agradece por tu colaboración.

Comment: @Juanzu nada que disculpar estamos para ayudar. Me alegra de que esta parte del problema se haya resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal ve la respuesta de @ACedano

Otro detalle es que en lugar de usar `id`, usa por ejemplo `id_prod`, trata de no usar palabras [reservadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZA_STOCK (n_cantidad int,  n_concepto enum, id_prod int)
BEGIN
if n_concepto='Entrada' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad+n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id_prod;
end if
if n_concepto='Salida' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad-n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id_prod;
end if;
END $$
```

Comment: gracias es buena practica lo que dices, pero Igual sigue con el error.

Comment: es el mismo error? =9 si no es así actualiza .

Comment: Si el mismo error.

Comment: Si cambiaste lo que comento y se muestra  "#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ' id int) ..." no es posible, revisa si cambio algo el mensaje.

Comment: Este es el error que me sale:  #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ' id_prod int)
BEGIN
if n_concepto='Entrada' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad' en la linea 1

Answer (score 0):

le encontré solución al problema y son los "DELIMITER" el problema esta en como abrir y cerrar el mismo---->

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZA_STOCK  
(n_cantidad int, n_concepto enum('Entrada', 'Salida'),  id int) 
BEGIN 
if n_concepto='Entrada' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad+n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if;
if n_concepto='Salida' then
UPDATE producto set cantidad=cantidad-n_cantidad WHERE id_producto=id;
end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

ASI ES COMO TENDRIA QUE QUEDAR Y FUNCIONARIA DE MARAVILLA.